# viewForZoomingInScrollView working but with extra blank space

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, zooming

I am trying to implement default photos app like functionality.

I have added an image view to scroll view and implemented below method:

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return self.fileDisplayImageView;
}
```

Problem is though it is zooming the image, it is adding space around its bounds when zoomed.

Below is the original image:

[image]

Here is the image after zoom, with extra blank space added at top:

[image]

Can any one suggest, how can I resolve this problem?

**Update:** Attaching the sample code: [ZoomSample](https://db.tt/wrNjTLkV)

**Update:** My initial problem is resolves after implementing solution suggested by Robert, thanx to him :-).

**Now my new problem is**- image is not appearing at center but is appearing aligned to top:

[image: Image aligned at top]

Comment: viewForZoomingInScrollView method depends on the subview of the scrollView. if your scrollview contains only imageview then above function will perfect well

Comment: hey buddy.. I have uploaded the sample code.. you can check over here: https://db.tt/wrNjTLkV

Answer (score 3):

You have some problems in your code, but this specific issue you are describing is because you are not defining the size of the image, you are creating an image with the frame height equal to the screen, so this empty space you are describing, actually is the image frame that you are zooming.

I made this small changes in your viewDidLoad, I hope it helps:

```
self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"kittens"]];
     [self.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

    self.scrollView.delegate = self;
    self.scrollView.contentSize = self.imageView.frame.size;
    self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 3.0;
    self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.36;

    [self.scrollView setZoomScale:0.36];

    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.imageView];
```

Comment: thnx buddy.. though this solved my problem.. I am now facing some alignment problem.. I have update my question for the same.. have a look

Comment: @Miraaj This probably will solve your problem:
self.imageView.center = self.scrollView.center;